# Is Ajax request persistent?

Tags: php, ajax

I was wondering if an ajax request is persistent ? An exemple :

On page 1 of my website, i fire an ajax request which call a php script for a specific process. This process can take more than 10 minutes. My question is: If i leave the page after the ajax call is fired, and before the process is finished, is the process aborded or still working untill it finishes ?

Comment: The process will continue until finished. Making an Ajax call is like opening a new website page.

Comment: An AJAX response that takes 10 minutes to return needs to be rethought. Can you make this a background process on the web server, and then periodically send an AJAX request to see if it is done?